# jupyter - display output of code cell in previous markdown cell

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly

I'm using jupyter to generate a report for people who may/may not care about code, and would like to have the relevant output (tables, plotly charts, etc) at the top of the document, with all the actual workhorse code coming later. is there a way for a markdown cell to display the output of a code cell that is later in the document? something like e.g.

```
[cell 5] "as can be seen in the following chart: {{X}}" 
... 
...
[cell 20] X=plot(data)
```

I'm not against a roundabout idea of saving the output to a file and have the markdown cell just rendering the file contents, I'm just hoping for an inline solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the output contents of a computed cell (e.g. `Cell[20]`) like so:

```
Out[20]
```

Comment: And how does that help with the question? I have one markdown cell, and one python cell; when I say `print(Out[0])` I get "Key Error", and that is because it turns out, `print(Out)` returns an empty dict.